# Take the different id from the same link click

Tags: javascript

In a source code of a page there is a unique external link in different parts of the page 4 times.

I want to trigger which click user clicked because some line before it there is an id I want to save it to a variable if the user click to the specific link.

A quick example:

```
<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id1">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id2">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id3">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>
```

How can I check if the user makes a click to the second link that the id is id2 and save it to a variable etc.? In my page there are also other hrefs but I want to check only the specific case.

Comment: Bind a click event to *all* `<a>` tags, then traverse up the DOM to `.mydiv`, then see if it contains any children that match `#id2`.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a basic DOM tutorial. It should cover DOM selection, event binding and basic DOM node traversal.

Comment: Instead of all `<a>` tags why not just `.mydiv a`?

Comment: You can't add any click event? Then how are you going to manage clicks?

Comment: @eabcde: You don't need to change the *initial* code, you can add an event listener at any point.

Comment: Is the link target a new window? Or is this code supposed to trigger before following the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the `click` event on these easily enough:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]');
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
}
```

Then in the handler, use `parentNode` repeatedly to find the `.mydiv`, then find the paragraph with the id:

```
function handleClick() {
    var mydiv = this.parentNode;
    var p;
    while (mydiv && !/\bmydiv\b/.test(mydiv.className)) {
        mydiv = mydiv.parentNode;
    }
    if (mydiv) {
        p = mydiv.querySelector("p[id]");
        if (p) {
            // Use p.id here, it's the ID
        }
    }
}
```

Note that once you're done processing the click, the page you're in will be torn down and replaced with the result of following the link. So if you grab the ID to a variable, you'll need to do something with it (like put it in local storage) right away.

Also note that your links are probably invalid, `href="www.outboundlink"` is a *relative* link within the site. It would need `http://`, `https://`, or `//` to go to another site.

**Live Example:**

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]');
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
  list[index].addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
}

function handleClick(e) {
  var mydiv = this.parentNode;
  var p;
  while (mydiv && !/\bmydiv\b/.test(mydiv.className)) {
    mydiv = mydiv.parentNode;
  }
  if (mydiv) {
    p = mydiv.querySelector("p[id]");
    if (p) {
      // Use p.id here, it's the ID
      alert("The ID is " + p.id);
    }
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // Just for demonstration purposes
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id1">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id2">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id3">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Like many DOM traversal things, this can be made much simpler using a DOM wrapper library like jQuery:

```
$('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]').on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("p[id]").attr("id");
    alert("The ID is " + id); // will be undefined if not found
});
```

```js
$('a[href="www.outboundlink.com"]').on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("p[id]").attr("id");
  alert("The ID is " + id);
  return false; // Just for demonstration purposes
});
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id1">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id2">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id3">test
    <p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
      </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just from curiousity in another div element with the same structure in first p I have an img element like this <p><img alt="" src="/images/img1.png" /></p> could also be possible to take the src from this using Jquery

Comment: @eabcde: Yes, of course. Have a read through [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) (only takes an hour or so, pays you back that time immediately). It would be along the lines of `var src = $(this).closest(".mydiv").find("img").attr("src");`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nice but there is no need to include also the p element?

Comment: @eabcde: No, `find` looks at all descendants, you don't need to give it a full path, just a selector that is sufficient to identify the element you want. You *could* do `.find("p img")` or `.find("p > img")`, but you don't have to unless there are other `img` elements you need to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the DOM to the right element.
First we find the div with class `myDiv` and then `p` element with `id` attribute.

```js
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var p = link.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("p[id]");
    alert(p.getAttribute('id'))    
  })
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id1">test</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id2">test</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="id3">test</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't mind using jQuery for it, the code is much shorter:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var first = $(this).closest('.mydiv').find('p:first');
  console.log(first.attr('id'))
})
```

Comment: You are welcome. Compare the amount of code that you need to write using jQuery and pure JavaScript .

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. If you don't have control over the created a elements and binding gets tricky, you can use delegation which saves you from traversing the DOM upwards.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div){
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName === 'A' && div.querySelector('p#id2')){
      alert('Found id2');
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id1">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id2">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
<p id="id3">test<p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div> <a href="www.outboundlink.com"> click </a> </div>
</div>
```